# Checking an if condition in a foreach only at the last index

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi I have a situation where I have an observable array of observable arrays.This is what my markup looks like:

```
<div class="slider-wrap cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" data-cycle-timeout="0" data-cycle-slides="> section" data-cycle-prev=".slider-nav .prev" data-cycle-next=".slider-nav .next" data-cycle-pager=".slider-bullets" data-bind="foreach: category().questions()">
    <section data-bind="foreach: $data">   
        <article>
            <!-- ko if: hasGrade-->
            <header data-bind="text: $data.description"></header>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
            </ul>
            <span data-bind="text: $parent.$index"></span>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: hasMemo-->
            <header data-bind="text: $data.memoTitle"></header>
            <textarea></textarea>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </article>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: $parent.$parent.hasMemo-->
        <article>
            <header data-bind="text: $parent.$parent.memoTitle"></header>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </article>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </section>
</div>
```

I can not change the structure of the markup because of a plugin that I am using and do not have the luxury of not using it.

The last if condition should only be checked when the last element is iterated.This is the model:

```
   {
memo: null,
categoryId: 1,
title: "Docent",
hasMemo: true,
memoIsMandatory: false,
memoTitle: "Docent Opmerkingen",
questions: [
[
{
memo: null,
grade: null,
description: "De docent is goed voorbereid",
memoTitle: "De docent is goed voorbereid",
questionId: 11,
hasGrade: false,
hasMemo: true,
showOnlyMemo: true
},
{
memo: null,
grade: null,
description: "De docent heeft kennis van zaken",
memoTitle: "De docent heeft kennis van zaken",
questionId: 12,
hasGrade: true,
hasMemo: false,
showOnlyMemo: false
},
{
memo: null,
grade: null,
description: "De docent kan de onderwerpen boeiend uitleggen",
memoTitle: "De docent kan de onderwerpen boeiend uitleggen",
questionId: 13,
hasGrade: true,
hasMemo: false,
showOnlyMemo: false
},
{
memo: null,
grade: null,
description: "De docent gaat goed in op de vragen uit de groep",
memoTitle: "De docent gaat goed in op de vragen uit de groep",
questionId: 14,
hasGrade: true,
hasMemo: false,
showOnlyMemo: false
},
{
memo: null,
grade: null,
description: "De docent stimuleert de groep tot actieve deelname",
memoTitle: "De docent stimuleert de groep tot actieve deelname",
questionId: 15,
hasGrade: true,
hasMemo: false,
showOnlyMemo: false
}
],
[
{
memo: null,
grade: null,
description: "De docent voegt inhoudelijk iets toe aan het studiemateriaal",
memoTitle: "De docent voegt inhoudelijk iets toe aan het studiemateriaal",
questionId: 16,
hasGrade: true,
hasMemo: false,
showOnlyMemo: false
},
{
memo: null,
grade: null,
description: "De docent is praktijkgericht",
memoTitle: "De docent is praktijkgericht",
questionId: 17,
hasGrade: true,
hasMemo: false,
showOnlyMemo: false
},
{
memo: null,
grade: null,
description: "Totaal oordeel over de docent",
memoTitle: "Totaal oordeel over de docent",
questionId: 18,
hasGrade: true,
hasMemo: false,
showOnlyMemo: false
}
]
]
},
{
memo: null,
categoryId: 7,
title: "Opbouw programma en studiemateriaal",
hasMemo: true,
memoIsMandatory: false,
memoTitle: "Opbouw programma en studiemateriaal Opmerkingen",
questions: [
[
{
memo: null,
grade: null,
description: "Het studieprogramma is duidelijk opgebouwd",
memoTitle: "Het studieprogramma is duidelijk opgebouwd",
questionId: 54,
hasGrade: true,
hasMemo: false,
showOnlyMemo: false
},
{
memo: null,
grade: null,
description: "Het studiemateriaal is compleet, goed leesbaar en praktijkgericht",
memoTitle: "Het studiemateriaal is compleet, goed leesbaar en praktijkgericht",
questionId: 55,
hasGrade: true,
hasMemo: false,
showOnlyMemo: false
}
]
]
}
]
```

In our case it's the element with the questionId 55.IS there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Knockout kindof depends on being able to change the markup.  Most plugins allow modifications of them.  What license is it under?  Otherwise, you need to manually set `hasMemo` to false on all of them.

Comment: I just got the ideea to bind the if condition to a function that will take as a parameter the parent observable array index and child observable array index with that I can check in my javascript what is the current element we are iterating over and return true or false.My only problem is that I do no know how to get the parent index can you assist me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `foreach` binding you can use special `$index` variable to refer to your position in the loop. Then the check is simple.

```
<!-- ko if: $parent.$parent.hasMemo() && $index() + 1 === $parent.length -->
<article>
    <header data-bind="text: $parent.$parent.memoTitle"></header>
    <textarea></textarea>
</article>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Note that when you use a complex JS expression in a binding (as opposed to the name of a single observable or variable) you need to unwrap your observables explicitly. Hence the parentheses in `$index()` and `$parent.$parent.hasMemo()`.